# MySQL mass delete from large innodb table very slow

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, delete

I have a innodb table which contains more than 120million rows including duplicates. Let's name it as `big_table`. I fetch all the duplicates into another table(`temp_big_table`) which contains nearly 40million records. So I run below procedure to chunk delete duplicate entries from `big_table`. (Without the chunk delete, I am getting *Error : no more space left over in system tablespace*.)

```
...

BEGIN
              
    DECLARE a BIGINT;
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM big_table INTO @lastId;
    
    SET a = strt; -- starting id goes here
   
    WHILE a <= @lastId DO
        DELETE FROM big_table USING big_table, temp_big_table
            WHERE big_table.id=temp_big_table.id
              AND big_table.id BETWEEN a AND a+99999;
        SET a = a + 100000;
        SELECT SLEEP(1);
    END WHILE;
    
END

...
```

Here are the structures of my two tables:

```
+------------------+                     +------------------+
| big_table        |                     | temp_big_table   |
+------------------+                     +------------------+
| id(bigint) pk    |                     | id(bigint)       | 
| name(varchar)    |                     +------------------+
| address(varchar) |
| mobile(varchar)  |
+------------------+
```

My innodb configurations are listed below:

```
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 4294967296
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend:MAX:1G
innodb_file_format  Barracuda
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_log_buffer_size  268435456
innodb_log_file_size    1073741824
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_write_io_threads 16
```

I called the stored procedure 15 hours ago and it is still executing. Any suggestions to optimize the task to complete much faster are welcome.

**UPDATE**

with @danblack's suggestions in the comments section

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteDuplicates`(IN `strt` BIGINT(20))
BEGIN
              
    DECLARE a BIGINT;
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM big_table INTO @lastId;
    
    SET a = strt; -- starting id goes here
   
    WHILE a <= @lastId DO
        DELETE FROM big_table USING big_table, temp_big_table
            WHERE big_table.id=temp_big_table.id
              AND big_table.id BETWEEN a AND a+99999;
        SET a = a + 100000;
        DELETE FROM temp_big_table WHERE id < a;
        SELECT SLEEP(1);
    END WHILE;
    
END
```

Comment: Does the io_capacity match the storage? Any reason temp_big_table's column isn't a primary key? Why not `DELETE FROM temp_big_table WHERE id < a` after the first delete is done?

Comment: You mean server storage ? it is 200GB with ubuntu server installed. Yeah.. I was just thinking the same thing, deleting completed sets from the `temp_table`.  Then I thought `WHERE big_table.id=temp_big_table.id` will take care of it. Anyway I will try that. I did not want to add pk to temp table. I will try that too. Thanks.

Comment: @danblack I applied all your suggestions. But still same speed. Maybe few seconds increased due to the delete statement, but it is worth to have in-case a query execution interruption occurred, I can start from the last deleted id.

Comment: `*io_capacity` is IOPs not volume size. A non-primary index on `temp_big_table` is a possible suitable second preference to a PK and should change the query plan (look at `EXPLAIN ... DELETE` but if PK didn't change this I doubt a secondary would. There is multi table delete syntax however it doesn't have a `LIMIT` clause. Are you running the call to this procedure inside a transaction?

Comment: No, not inside a transaction. Just calling it in the terminal.

Comment: @danblack I updated the procedure in the question.

Comment: change `innodb_io_capacity/innodb_io_capacity_max` to your IOPs capacity on the device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126932/discussion-between-madushan-perera-and-danblack).